# Android: Limit WebView text to a single line?

Tags: java, webview

Very simple question that I could not find the answer for: If I have a textual WebView, is it possible to make it so that the text won't be wrapped, and had just one line?

For example:

`String string = "this is a long text that will be wrapped";`

Will normally be displayed:

`This is a long
 text that will
 be wrapped`

I need it to be a single line in the WebView. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
String start = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /><style> body {
white-space: nowrap;}</style></head><body>";

String end = "</body></html>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, start + yourContent + end, null, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

**white-space: nowrap;** makes your test single line when you apply in style